# XSLT for recursive XML element

Tags: html, xml, recursion, xslt

I am working on an XML standard for swimming programs. I created an [XML schema and some example XML files](https://github.com/bartneck/swiML). Since swimming programs often use repetitions (e.g. 4 x 100m Freestyle), I created an XML element `<instruction>` that can include further instances of itself. It uses the `<XS:choice>` to either include a `<repetition>` (e.g 4 x) or direct swimming instructions (100m Freestyle). A `<repetition>` can then include further repetitions and/or direct swimming instructions. Here is an example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<program xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:/Users/cba56/Dropbox%20(UC%20Enterprise)/swimML/oxygen/swiML.xsd">

    <!-- Complex program with repetitions and loops -->

    <title>Complex Program</title>
    <author>
        <firstName>Christoph</firstName>
        <lastName>Bartneck</lastName>
        <email>christoph@bartneck.de</email>
    </author>
    <author>
        <firstName>Matthias</firstName>
        <lastName>MccCurdy</lastName>
        <email>mc@swim.com</email>
    </author>
    <creationDate>2022-06-30</creationDate>
    <poolLength>25</poolLength>
    <poolLengthUnit>meters</poolLengthUnit>
    <defaultInstructionLengthUnit>meters</defaultInstructionLengthUnit>

    <!-- Examples of a veriety of instructions -->

    <instruction>
        <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
        <rest><afterStop>PT20S</afterStop></rest>
        <intensity><staticIntensity>
                <precentageEffort>70</precentageEffort>
            </staticIntensity></intensity>
        <stroke><standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke></stroke>
        <equipment>pads</equipment>
        <equipment>pullBuoy</equipment>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
        <rest><sinceStart>PT1M45S</sinceStart></rest>
        <intensity><staticIntensity>
                <precentageEffort>70</precentageEffort>
            </staticIntensity></intensity>
        <stroke><kicking>
                <orientation>front</orientation>
                <legMovement>flutter</legMovement>
            </kicking></stroke>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <lengthAsDistance>400</lengthAsDistance>
        <rest><inOut>3</inOut></rest>
        <intensity>
            <startIntensity>
                <precentageEffort>60</precentageEffort>
            </startIntensity>
            <stopIntensity>
                <precentageEffort>100</precentageEffort>
            </stopIntensity>
        </intensity>
        <stroke><standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke></stroke>
    </instruction>

    <!-- An example of a simple repetition -->
    <!-- It uses IM as the repetition stroke, so 100FL, 100BK, 100BR, 100FR -->
    <instruction>
        <repetition>
            <repetitionCount>4</repetitionCount>
            <stroke><standardStroke>individualMedley</standardStroke></stroke>
            <instruction>
                <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
                <rest><sinceStart>PT1M45S</sinceStart></rest>
                <intensity><staticIntensity>
                        <zone>tempo</zone>
                    </staticIntensity></intensity>
            </instruction>
        </repetition>
    </instruction>

    <!-- Example of a repeition changing intensity.  -->
    <!-- This would be a build exercise -->
    <instruction>
        <repetition>
            <repetitionCount>4</repetitionCount>
            <intensity>
                <startIntensity>
                    <precentageEffort>60</precentageEffort>
                </startIntensity>
                <stopIntensity>
                    <precentageEffort>100</precentageEffort>
                </stopIntensity>
            </intensity>
            <instruction>
                <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
                <stroke><standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke></stroke>
                <breath>5</breath>
            </instruction>
        </repetition>
    </instruction>

    <!-- Exmaple of a repeition inside a repetition -->
    <instruction>
        <repetition>
            <repetitionCount>4</repetitionCount>
            <instruction>
                <repetition>
                    <repetitionCount>2</repetitionCount>
                    <instruction>
                        <lengthAsDistance>50</lengthAsDistance>
                        <stroke><standardStroke>backstroke</standardStroke></stroke>
                    </instruction>
                    <instruction>
                        <lengthAsDistance>50</lengthAsDistance>
                        <stroke><standardStroke>breaststroke</standardStroke></stroke>
                    </instruction>
                </repetition>
            </instruction>
            <instruction>
                <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
                <stroke><standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke></stroke>
            </instruction>
        </repetition>
    </instruction>

    <!-- some basic instructions -->
    <instruction>
        <lengthAsTime>PT2M30S</lengthAsTime>
        <lenghUnit>time</lenghUnit>
        <stroke><standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke></stroke>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <lengthAsTime>PT1M30S</lengthAsTime>
        <stroke><standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke></stroke>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <lengthAsDistance>8</lengthAsDistance>
        <lenghUnit>laps</lenghUnit>
        <intensity><staticIntensity>
                <zone>endurance</zone>
            </staticIntensity></intensity>
        <stroke><standardStroke>backstroke</standardStroke></stroke>
    </instruction>
</program>
```

I am now trying to use XSLT to convert [instance1.xml](https://github.com/bartneck/swiML/blob/main/instance1.xml) to something like [goal.xhtml](https://github.com/bartneck/swiML/blob/main/goal.xhtml). Here is the goal.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Complex Program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Complex Program</h1>
        <h2>Description:</h2>
        <p></p>
        <p>Target Pool Length: 25 meters</p>
        <p>Default Length Unit: meters</p>
        <p>Creation Date: 30 June 2022</p>
        <h2>Authors:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Christoph Bartneck, christoph@bartneck.de</li>
            <li>Matthias MccCurdy, </li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Program:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>100 FR w20 70% Pads and Pullboy</li>
            <li>100 Kick Front Flutter @1:45 70%</li>
            <li>400 FR 3nd in 1st out 60%</li>
            <li>4x IM <ul>
                    <li>100 @1:45 Tempo</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>4x build 60%-100% <ul>
                    <li>100 FR b5</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>4x <ul>
                    <li>2x <ul>
                            <li>50 BK</li>
                            <li>50 BR</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>200 FR</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>2:30 FR</li>
            <li>8L BK Endurance</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

While I was able to get the basic XSLT transformation going (e.g. `<author>`), I am struggling with the recursive nature of the XML Schema and the `<instruction>`' element. I just can't get my head around how to even start with a solution.

Is there anybody out there who could maybe have a look at the XML file examples and suggest a strategy for the XSLT transformation?

Comment: Consider: The intent of SO is that OTHERS (not just you) can benefit from the question and answer.  You have linked all the relevant source code from another site.  When those links go 404, the question becomes useless.  Please include the code in your question.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but FYI there's a typo in your schema in the name of the element `lenghUnit`

Comment: Thank you Conal! Much appreciated. This is a very early version.

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy in XSLT for dealing with recursive XML structures (i.e. elements which can contain other elements of the same type) is to use template matching. You would create a template which matches the element concerned (e.g. `<xsl:template match="instruction">`); the template then produces some output, and also uses `xsl:apply-templates` to process child elements, which (assuming there are child elements of the same type) is effectively a recursive call to the same template.

Comment: What makes this XML file a bit more complicated is that within `<instructions>` you have a XS:choise element. I guess we would have to test the type of child and then apply a templated depending on that. But how that fits into the recursive nature remains a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Reinforcing @ConalTuohy's answer, the standard design pattern for XSLT stylesheets handles recursion without you even needing to think about it. Ask yourself "what do I need to do when I encounter an `instruction` element?", and the answer will probably be something like "generate a `ul` element with `li` elements for its children.". So write a template rule something like

```
<xsl:template match="instruction">
 <ul>
   <xsl:for-each select"child::node()">
     <li><xsl:apply-templates select="."/></li.
   </xsl:for-each>
 </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: this answer relates to the general question of "how do I get started". I haven't studied your input and output in any detail.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. This should solve the problem:

```
<xsl:template match="instruction">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="repetition"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="lengthAsDistance"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="lengthAsTime" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="repetition">
    <li>Repetition Count: <xsl:value-of select="repetitionCount"/></li>
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="instruction"/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>
```